# Copying a cell and pasting in another app pastes the formula not the value

Tags: excel-online

Excel-online is copying the cell formula, not the cell value to the computers clipboard, e.g.

Given that I copy a cell showing a value in Excel online

[image]

When I paste, the formula is pasted instead of the value.

[image]

I was expecting the number "2" to be pasted.  This is what used to happen.

This suddenly started happening today on a spreadsheet that we have been using for weeks.  The same thing happens when I create a new spreadsheet.

If I open the spreadsheet in Excel desktop, the value is pasted as expected.

Comment: This still pates the formula in other apps.  It does nothing when pasting back into Excel online.

Comment: what do you mean by "other apps"?

Comment: By other apps I mean anything other than excel online, e.g. the Start-Run dialog in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

A day later and my excel-online spreadsheets are pasting as expected.  Feels like A/B test.